# LISP recursive pairing?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to LISP and I'm trying to create a recursive function that pairs the elements within a list. I'm stuck on the last part of my function with adding in the recursion.

```
(defun pairup (L)
(cond((null L) nil))
(list (cons (car L) (cadr L)(pairup(cdr L)))))
```

I know that `(pairup(cdr L))))))` will show an error because its a third argument going into cons. Not sure how to add in the function again =/

INPUT: `(pairup'(1 2 3 4))`

OUTPUT: `((1 2) (3 4))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the function:

```
(defun pairup (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((null (cdr l)) (list l))   
        (t (cons (list (car l) (cadr l))
                 (pairup (cddr l))))))

(pairup '(1 2 3 4))   ;  produces ((1 2) (3 4))
(pairup '(1 2 3))     ;  produces ((1 2) (3))
```

Note that the second branch of the `cond` is to terminate the recursion when only one element is left, and this is necessary if the initial list has an odd number of elements. The syntax of the `cond` requires that the first form of a branch be always a condition, and in the last branch the condition is `t` to catch all the other cases.

Comment: Ah. I see. The original code would produce `((1 . 2) (3))` for `(pair-up '(1 2 3))` and your code produces `((1 2) (3))` (I was relying more on the code in the answer and retract my comment).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was finally able to get it =)